# Calculate Binomial Probability of number 75 out of total 100 rows and each row containing 3 random numbers

Tags: probability, statistics

Im trying to calculate the chance or probability of number **75** appearing. I have total 100 rows in microsoft excel and have frequency of number **75**. Each row contains 3 cells and each cell contains a random number between 1-100. For example typical table cells:

```
75 23 01
91 64 67
05 12 75
```

Im trying to use the formula:

```
P(k out of N) = (N! / (k!(N-k)!)) * (pk)(qN-k)
```

where:

```
N = 100 Total rows
k = 15 Number of times number 75 appears in these 100 rows
p = ?
q = 1 - q
```

Im stuck on calculating **p**.

**Notes:** numbers never repeat in the same cell. meaning there **will never be** a case like:

```
 75 75 22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers are random, the probability of $75$ appearing in any one row is $0.03$.  That is your $p$.  This counts on the fact that numbers are not repeated within a row.

Comment: why 0.03? they are random but the range is between 1-100 it cant be 101

Comment: Yes, you are selecting 3 numbers out of 100, so the chance that any given number is selected is 0.03.  If you had one number per row it would be 0.01, for 3 (taken without replacement) it is 0.03.

Comment: so if instead 100 rows the range would be 121 then it would be what how would I calculate it? right now its 100 but what if later I would want to increase it

Comment: It would be 3/121 then.

Comment: got it, thank you, the other variables are correct? the way im calculating it

Comment: Yes, but you need some formatting.  There are powers in there that you have not shown.